# Neon intrinsic code not boosting performance compared to C code

Tags: c, simd, neon

I have a simple C code that subtracts 'num' no. of values from two different pointers and writes back into a third pointer. I tried the same code using neon intrinsics to boost the performance, but am unable to see any reduction in the code execution time. I am using ARM Cortex-A9 processor.

Below is my C code:

```
int code_c(uint8_t *in1, uint8_t *in2, uint8_t *out, uint32_t num)
{
  uint32_t i;

  for(i = 0; i < (num); i++) {

    out[i] = in1[i] - in2[i];
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The corresponding neon intrinisic code is as follows:

```
#include <arm_neon.h>

int code_neon(uint8_t * __restrict in1, uint8_t * __restrict    in2, uint8_t * __restrict y, uint32_t num)
{
  uint32_t   i;
  uint8x8_t s1, s2;
  uint8x8_t out;

  num = num/8;

  for (i = num; i != 0; i--) {

    s1 = vld1_u8(in1);
    s2 = vld1_u8(in2);

    out  = vsub_u8(s1, s2);
    vst1_u8(y, out);

    in1+=8; in2+=8;y+=8;

    __builtin_prefetch(in1+8);
    __builtin_prefetch(in2+8);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

What's going wrong here?

The generated assembly code for Neon :

```
00000000 <code_neon(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)>:
0:  e92d4008    push    {r3, lr}
4:  e52de004    push    {lr}        ; (str lr, [sp, #-4]!)
  8:    ebfffffe    bl  0 <__gnu_mcount_nc>
        8: R_ARM_CALL   __gnu_mcount_nc
  c:    e1b031a3    lsrs    r3, r3, #3
10: 0a00000d    beq 4c <code_neon(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)+0x4c>
14: e280e008    add lr, r0, #8
18: e281c008    add ip, r1, #8
1c: f460070f    vld1.8  {d16}, [r0]
20: e2533001    subs    r3, r3, #1
24: e1a0000e    mov r0, lr
28: e28ee008    add lr, lr, #8
2c: f461170f    vld1.8  {d17}, [r1]
30: e1a0100c    mov r1, ip
34: e28cc008    add ip, ip, #8
38: f5def000    pld [lr]
3c: f34008a1    vsub.i8 d16, d16, d17
40: f5dcf000    pld [ip]
44: f442070d    vst1.8  {d16}, [r2]!
48: 1afffff3    bne 1c <code_neon(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)+0x1c>
4c: e3a00000    mov r0, #0
50: e8bd8008    pop {r3, pc}
```

The assembly code for C :

```
00000000 <code_c(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)>:
0:  e92d43f8    push    {r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, lr}
4:  e52de004    push    {lr}        ; (str lr, [sp, #-4]!)
8:  ebfffffe    bl  0 <__gnu_mcount_nc>
        8: R_ARM_CALL   __gnu_mcount_nc
c:  e3530000    cmp r3, #0
10: 0a0000f1    beq 3dc <code_c(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)+0x3dc>
14: e282c010    add ip, r2, #16
18: e280e010    add lr, r0, #16
1c: e152000e    cmp r2, lr
20: 3150000c    cmpcc   r0, ip
24: e2814010    add r4, r1, #16
28: 23a0e001    movcs   lr, #1
2c: 33a0e000    movcc   lr, #0
30: e1520004    cmp r2, r4
34: 3151000c    cmpcc   r1, ip
38: 23a0c001    movcs   ip, #1
3c: 33a0c000    movcc   ip, #0
40: e00cc00e    and ip, ip, lr
44: e3530013    cmp r3, #19
48: 93a0c000    movls   ip, #0
4c: 820cc001    andhi   ip, ip, #1
50: e35c0000    cmp ip, #0
54: 0a0000e2    beq 3e4 <code_c(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)+0x3e4>
58: e200c007    and ip, r0, #7
5c: e26cc000    rsb ip, ip, #0
60: e20cc00f    and ip, ip, #15
64: e15c0003    cmp ip, r3
68: 21a0c003    movcs   ip, r3
6c: e35c0000    cmp ip, #0
70: 0a000059    beq 1dc <code_c(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)+0x1dc>
74: e5d0e000    ldrb    lr, [r0]
78: e35c0001    cmp ip, #1
7c: e5d14000    ldrb    r4, [r1]
80: e064e00e    rsb lr, r4, lr
84: e5c2e000    strb    lr, [r2]
88: 0a000053    beq 1dc <code_c(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)+0x1dc>
8c: e5d0e001    ldrb    lr, [r0, #1]
90: e35c0002    cmp ip, #2
94: e5d14001    ldrb    r4, [r1, #1]
98: e064e00e    rsb lr, r4, lr
9c: e5c2e001    strb    lr, [r2, #1]
a0: 0a00004d    beq 1dc <code_c(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)+0x1dc>
a4: e5d0e002    ldrb    lr, [r0, #2]
a8: e35c0003    cmp ip, #3
ac: e5d14002    ldrb    r4, [r1, #2]
b0: e064e00e    rsb lr, r4, lr
b4: e5c2e002    strb    lr, [r2, #2]
b8: 0a000047    beq 1dc <code_c(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)+0x1dc>
bc: e5d0e003    ldrb    lr, [r0, #3]
c0: e35c0004    cmp ip, #4
c4: e5d14003    ldrb    r4, [r1, #3]
c8: e064e00e    rsb lr, r4, lr
cc: e5c2e003    strb    lr, [r2, #3]
d0: 0a000041    beq 1dc <code_c(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)+0x1dc>
d4: e5d0e004    ldrb    lr, [r0, #4]
d8: e35c0005    cmp ip, #5
dc: e5d14004    ldrb    r4, [r1, #4]
e0: e064e00e    rsb lr, r4, lr
e4: e5c2e004    strb    lr, [r2, #4]
e8: 0a00003b    beq 1dc <code_c(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)+0x1dc>
ec: e5d0e005    ldrb    lr, [r0, #5]
f0: e35c0006    cmp ip, #6
f4: e5d14005    ldrb    r4, [r1, #5]
f8: e064e00e    rsb lr, r4, lr
fc: e5c2e005    strb    lr, [r2, #5]
100:    0a000035    beq 1dc <code_c(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)+0x1dc>
104:    e5d0e006    ldrb    lr, [r0, #6]
108:    e35c0007    cmp ip, #7
10c:    e5d14006    ldrb    r4, [r1, #6]
110:    e064e00e    rsb lr, r4, lr
114:    e5c2e006    strb    lr, [r2, #6]
118:    0a0000be    beq 418 <code_c(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)+0x418>
11c:    e5d0e007    ldrb    lr, [r0, #7]
120:    e35c0008    cmp ip, #8
124:    e5d14007    ldrb    r4, [r1, #7]
128:    e064e00e    rsb lr, r4, lr
12c:    e5c2e007    strb    lr, [r2, #7]
130:    0a000029    beq 1dc <code_c(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)+0x1dc>
134:    e5d0e008    ldrb    lr, [r0, #8]
138:    e35c0009    cmp ip, #9
13c:    e5d14008    ldrb    r4, [r1, #8]
140:    e064e00e    rsb lr, r4, lr
144:    e5c2e008    strb    lr, [r2, #8]
148:    0a000023    beq 1dc <code_c(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)+0x1dc>
14c:    e5d0e009    ldrb    lr, [r0, #9]
150:    e35c000a    cmp ip, #10
154:    e5d14009    ldrb    r4, [r1, #9]
158:    e064e00e    rsb lr, r4, lr
15c:    e5c2e009    strb    lr, [r2, #9]
160:    0a00001d    beq 1dc <code_c(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)+0x1dc>
164:    e5d0e00a    ldrb    lr, [r0, #10]
168:    e35c000b    cmp ip, #11
16c:    e5d1400a    ldrb    r4, [r1, #10]
170:    e064e00e    rsb lr, r4, lr
174:    e5c2e00a    strb    lr, [r2, #10]
178:    0a000017    beq 1dc <code_c(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)+0x1dc>
17c:    e5d0e00b    ldrb    lr, [r0, #11]
180:    e35c000c    cmp ip, #12
184:    e5d1400b    ldrb    r4, [r1, #11]
188:    e064e00e    rsb lr, r4, lr
18c:    e5c2e00b    strb    lr, [r2, #11]
190:    0a000011    beq 1dc <code_c(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)+0x1dc>
194:    e5d0e00c    ldrb    lr, [r0, #12]
198:    e35c000d    cmp ip, #13
19c:    e5d1400c    ldrb    r4, [r1, #12]
1a0:    e064e00e    rsb lr, r4, lr
1a4:    e5c2e00c    strb    lr, [r2, #12]
1a8:    0a00000b    beq 1dc <code_c(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)+0x1dc>
1ac:    e5d0e00d    ldrb    lr, [r0, #13]
1b0:    e35c000f    cmp ip, #15
1b4:    e5d1400d    ldrb    r4, [r1, #13]
1b8:    e064e00e    rsb lr, r4, lr
1bc:    e5c2e00d    strb    lr, [r2, #13]
1c0:    1a000092    bne 410 <code_c(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)+0x410>
1c4:    e5d0400e    ldrb    r4, [r0, #14]
1c8:    e1a0e00c    mov lr, ip
1cc:    e5d1500e    ldrb    r5, [r1, #14]
1d0:    e0654004    rsb r4, r5, r4
1d4:    e5c2400e    strb    r4, [r2, #14]
1d8:    ea000000    b   1e0 <code_c(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)+0x1e0>
1dc:    e1a0e00c    mov lr, ip
1e0:    e06c6003    rsb r6, ip, r3
1e4:    e2435001    sub r5, r3, #1
1e8:    e2464010    sub r4, r6, #16
1ec:    e06c5005    rsb r5, ip, r5
1f0:    e1a04224    lsr r4, r4, #4
1f4:    e355000e    cmp r5, #14
1f8:    e2844001    add r4, r4, #1
1fc:    e1a05204    lsl r5, r4, #4
200:    9a000010    bls 248 <code_c(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)+0x248>
204:    e080900c    add r9, r0, ip
208:    e081800c    add r8, r1, ip
20c:    e3a07000    mov r7, #0
210:    e082c00c    add ip, r2, ip
214:    f4690adf    vld1.64 {d16-d17}, [r9 :64]
218:    e2877001    add r7, r7, #1
21c:    e1570004    cmp r7, r4
220:    e2899010    add r9, r9, #16
224:    f4682a0f    vld1.8  {d18-d19}, [r8]
228:    e2888010    add r8, r8, #16
22c:    f34008e2    vsub.i8 q8, q8, q9
230:    f44c0a0f    vst1.8  {d16-d17}, [ip]
234:    e28cc010    add ip, ip, #16
238:    3afffff5    bcc 214 <code_c(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)+0x214>
23c:    e1560005    cmp r6, r5
240:    e08ee005    add lr, lr, r5
244:    0a000064    beq 3dc <code_c(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)+0x3dc>
248:    e7d0c00e    ldrb    ip, [r0, lr]
24c:    e28e4001    add r4, lr, #1
250:    e7d1500e    ldrb    r5, [r1, lr]
254:    e1530004    cmp r3, r4
258:    e065c00c    rsb ip, r5, ip
25c:    e7c2c00e    strb    ip, [r2, lr]
260:    9a00005d    bls 3dc <code_c(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)+0x3dc>
264:    e7d05004    ldrb    r5, [r0, r4]
268:    e28ec002    add ip, lr, #2
26c:    e7d16004    ldrb    r6, [r1, r4]
270:    e153000c    cmp r3, ip
274:    e0665005    rsb r5, r6, r5
278:    e7c25004    strb    r5, [r2, r4]
27c:    9a000056    bls 3dc <code_c(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)+0x3dc>
280:    e7d0500c    ldrb    r5, [r0, ip]
284:    e28e4003    add r4, lr, #3
288:    e7d1600c    ldrb    r6, [r1, ip]
28c:    e1530004    cmp r3, r4
290:    e0665005    rsb r5, r6, r5
294:    e7c2500c    strb    r5, [r2, ip]
298:    9a00004f    bls 3dc <code_c(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)+0x3dc>
29c:    e7d05004    ldrb    r5, [r0, r4]
2a0:    e28ec004    add ip, lr, #4
2a4:    e7d16004    ldrb    r6, [r1, r4]
2a8:    e153000c    cmp r3, ip
2ac:    e0665005    rsb r5, r6, r5
2b0:    e7c25004    strb    r5, [r2, r4]
2b4:    9a000048    bls 3dc <code_c(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)+0x3dc>
2b8:    e7d0500c    ldrb    r5, [r0, ip]
2bc:    e28e4005    add r4, lr, #5
2c0:    e7d1600c    ldrb    r6, [r1, ip]
2c4:    e1530004    cmp r3, r4
2c8:    e0665005    rsb r5, r6, r5
2cc:    e7c2500c    strb    r5, [r2, ip]
2d0:    9a000041    bls 3dc <code_c(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)+0x3dc>
2d4:    e7d05004    ldrb    r5, [r0, r4]
2d8:    e28ec006    add ip, lr, #6
2dc:    e7d16004    ldrb    r6, [r1, r4]
2e0:    e153000c    cmp r3, ip
2e4:    e0665005    rsb r5, r6, r5
2e8:    e7c25004    strb    r5, [r2, r4]
2ec:    9a00003a    bls 3dc <code_c(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)+0x3dc>
2f0:    e7d0500c    ldrb    r5, [r0, ip]
2f4:    e28e4007    add r4, lr, #7
2f8:    e7d1600c    ldrb    r6, [r1, ip]
2fc:    e1530004    cmp r3, r4
300:    e0665005    rsb r5, r6, r5
304:    e7c2500c    strb    r5, [r2, ip]
 308:   9a000033    bls 3dc <code_c(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)+0x3dc>
 30c:   e7d05004    ldrb    r5, [r0, r4]
 310:   e28ec008    add ip, lr, #8
 314:   e7d16004    ldrb    r6, [r1, r4]
 318:   e153000c    cmp r3, ip
 31c:   e0665005    rsb r5, r6, r5
 320:   e7c25004    strb    r5, [r2, r4]
 324:   9a00002c    bls 3dc <code_c(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)+0x3dc>
 328:   e7d0500c    ldrb    r5, [r0, ip]
 32c:   e28e4009    add r4, lr, #9
 330:   e7d1600c    ldrb    r6, [r1, ip]
 334:   e1530004    cmp r3, r4
 338:   e0665005    rsb r5, r6, r5
 33c:   e7c2500c    strb    r5, [r2, ip]
 340:   9a000025    bls 3dc <code_c(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)+0x3dc>
 344:   e7d05004    ldrb    r5, [r0, r4]
 348:   e28ec00a    add ip, lr, #10
 34c:   e7d16004    ldrb    r6, [r1, r4]
 350:   e153000c    cmp r3, ip
 354:   e0665005    rsb r5, r6, r5
 358:   e7c25004    strb    r5, [r2, r4]
 35c:   9a00001e    bls 3dc <code_c(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)+0x3dc>
 360:   e7d0500c    ldrb    r5, [r0, ip]
 364:   e28e400b    add r4, lr, #11
 368:   e7d1600c    ldrb    r6, [r1, ip]
 36c:   e1530004    cmp r3, r4
 370:   e0665005    rsb r5, r6, r5
 374:   e7c2500c    strb    r5, [r2, ip]
 378:   9a000017    bls 3dc <code_c(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)+0x3dc>
 37c:   e7d05004    ldrb    r5, [r0, r4]
 380:   e28ec00c    add ip, lr, #12
 384:   e7d16004    ldrb    r6, [r1, r4]
 388:   e153000c    cmp r3, ip
 38c:   e0665005    rsb r5, r6, r5
 390:   e7c25004    strb    r5, [r2, r4]
 394:   9a000010    bls 3dc <code_c(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)+0x3dc>
 398:   e7d0500c    ldrb    r5, [r0, ip]
 39c:   e28e400d    add r4, lr, #13
 3a0:   e7d1600c    ldrb    r6, [r1, ip]
 3a4:   e1530004    cmp r3, r4
 3a8:   e0665005    rsb r5, r6, r5
 3ac:   e7c2500c    strb    r5, [r2, ip]
 3b0:   9a000009    bls 3dc <code_c(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)+0x3dc>
 3b4:   e7d05004    ldrb    r5, [r0, r4]
 3b8:   e28ec00e    add ip, lr, #14
 3bc:   e7d1e004    ldrb    lr, [r1, r4]
 3c0:   e153000c    cmp r3, ip
 3c4:   e06e3005    rsb r3, lr, r5
 3c8:   e7c23004    strb    r3, [r2, r4]
 3cc:   87d0300c    ldrbhi  r3, [r0, ip]
 3d0:   87d1100c    ldrbhi  r1, [r1, ip]
 3d4:   80613003    rsbhi   r3, r1, r3
 3d8:   87c2300c    strbhi  r3, [r2, ip]
 3dc:   e3a00000    mov r0, #0
 3e0:   e8bd83f8    pop {r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, pc}
 3e4:   e2411001    sub r1, r1, #1
 3e8:   e0803003    add r3, r0, r3
 3ec:   e2422001    sub r2, r2, #1
 3f0:   e4d0c001    ldrb    ip, [r0], #1
 3f4:   e5f1e001    ldrb    lr, [r1, #1]!
 3f8:   e1500003    cmp r0, r3
 3fc:   e06ec00c    rsb ip, lr, ip
 400:   e5e2c001    strb    ip, [r2, #1]!
 404:   1afffff9    bne 3f0 <code_c(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)+0x3f0>
 408:   e3a00000    mov r0, #0
 40c:   e8bd83f8    pop {r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, pc}
 410:   e3a0e00e    mov lr, #14
 414:   eaffff71    b   1e0 <code_c(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)+0x1e0>
 418:   e3a0e007    mov lr, #7
 41c:   eaffff6f    b   1e0 <code_c(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)+0x1e0>
```

Comment: So the obvious questions first: 1. How did you measure the performance (difference)? 2. How does the generated assembly look like for both?

Comment: What compiler options are you using? With a sufficient level of optimisation, it's possible that your compiler might auto-vectorise the first loop (and without optimisation, don't even bother measuring 'performance'). Ultimately you're doing an almost-entirely-memory-bound operation, so vectorisation isn't going to work miracles in any case. Furthermore prefetching close enough to hit in the _current_ cache line is pointless - to actually be useful, you need to prefetch 32-64 bytes ahead (i.e. 1-2 cache lines), and ideally process an entire cache line per loop iteration.

Comment: @UnholySheep : 1. I am using a Xilinx tool for compilation and its inbuilt 'Time stamp' function to measure performance. 2. I added assembly for neon  code only, as the assembly code for C is really lenghty (nearly 250 lines).

Comment: @Notlikethat : I am using O-3 level optimization. Compiler options are : 

__"-mcpu=cortex-a9 -mfpu=neon -ftree-vectorize -mfloat-abi=softfp -mno-lint -mdev-no-llvm"__

Comment: Right, so you're explicitly telling the compiler that it can use NEON, and to auto-vectorise some code which is trivially vectorisable, and are surprised that it does exactly what you ask it to? :P

Comment: @Notlikethat : I have only given the  **-O3** flag during C code compilation and rest of all flags (**"-mcpu=cortex-a9 -mfpu=neon -ftree-vectorize -mfloat-abi=softfp -mno-lint -mdev-no-llvm"**) during Neon code compilation. I read [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) that O3 optimization flag tells the compiler to pretty much optimize the code, but what i expect is, by enabling neon, added along to O3 flag, should further reduce the execution time. This [example](http://hilbert-space.de/?p=22) gave me pretty good results and i followed the same procedure.

Comment: @Notlikethat I increased the prefetch to 64 bytes as you pointed out and the execution time dropped to 7.75 ms for neon. Any other comments on the code are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that your C compiler, and more specifically its ARM backend, knows a few things about the ARM architecture you are compiling for. And your example is so extremely simple and commonplace that there's probably an optimization for exactly that :)

Manual optimization of code works best for cases that are strange and uncommon so the compiler just gives up and does a straightforward 1 : 1 translation to linear code with an actual non-unrolled loop, which then of course can be vastly improved by manual optimization :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. 1. Doesn't the execution time depend on the number of assembly instructions generated? Because there is a clear difference in the number of instructions generated for C code to Neon code. 2. There are supposed to be 8 parallel operations on Neon compared to single on C. Shouldn't the neon be obviously faster? Please correct me if i'm sounding silly.

Comment: It's really hard to tell until you post some data about your test, like how many values, and what were your results in seconds, &. :)

Comment: I tested for 2073600 values. I got an execution time of 9.82 milli seconds for C and 9.1 ms for Neon.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler wrote this (buried inside of a lot of setup code to take care of edge cases):

```
214:    f4690adf    vld1.64 {d16-d17}, [r9 :64]
218:    e2877001    add r7, r7, #1
21c:    e1570004    cmp r7, r4
220:    e2899010    add r9, r9, #16
224:    f4682a0f    vld1.8  {d18-d19}, [r8]
228:    e2888010    add r8, r8, #16
22c:    f34008e2    vsub.i8 q8, q8, q9
230:    f44c0a0f    vst1.8  {d16-d17}, [ip]
234:    e28cc010    add ip, ip, #16
238:    3afffff5    bcc 214 <code_c(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)+0x214>
```

My NEON is very rusty, and I'm not going to decode each line here (I'd get it wrong; hopefully someone will provide a more complete answer), but this is loading 16 bytes at a time into two 128-bit registers, subtracting all 16 from each other in parallel, and then writing them all back to the target. So this is doing the vectorization you were looking for. The fact that your NEON code is possibly slightly faster than the compiler's is at least partially because you don't check the edge case where `n` is not divisible by 8. The compiler does.

In most cases, intrinsics are not going to be helpful. If you are trying to beat the compiler, you're going to need to handle the entire pipeline yourself, and intrinsics aren't powerful enough for that. You need to be able to pick your registers, decide when to read and write memory, and very carefully manage your data layout to even begin to beat the compiler (since it's already doing all of that).

Why is the compiler's parallel behavior often better than hand-written even when you write basically the same things? Well, how do you manage faults? Assembly instructions do not run in series; many of them run in parallel. Often when you execute an expensive instruction, you may not be able to read the result for several clock cycles. If you try, the processor has to stop and wait. To avoid this problem, you often write assembly in very strange orders, like "start computation, load next data, write result of computation." That's really hard to pull off with intrinsics.

---

To a few of your comments in @yeoman's answer:

1. Doesn't the execution time depend on the number of assembly instructions generated?

Absolutely not. Execution time depends on the number of assembly instructions executed and what those instructions are and in what order they are executed. Very, very often (almost always) faster code is longer code in assembly. (The converse is not promised of course…) The most famous example of this is loop unrolling. Cut-and-pasting an operation 3 times in a row is going to be faster than a loop that counts to 3. Avoiding branching alone is going to be massive there. So the compiler automatically unrolls small loops when it knows beforehand the number of iterations.

2. There are supposed to be 8 parallel operations on Neon compared to single on C.

There are supposed to be 8 parallel operations, and the compiler generates that. But your code doesn't; it does one at a time.

Just using the NEON does magically make it go faster; the compiler already uses the NEON.

For a slightly different issue (discussing the Accelerate framework in iOS), but still addressing the same basic issues, see [Introduction to Fast Bezier](http://robnapier.net/fast-bezier-intro).

Also to reiterate @yeoman's point: If some very simple and mechanical change could make your C code go much faster, the compiler would just do that for you (and it does).

Comment: FWIW, the auto-vectorised code is actually doing 16 bytes at a time (hence the length of the scalar intro/outro). Otherwise, though, you shouldn't need to explain it as it's unsurprisingly doing the exact same operations as the manually-vectorised version ;)

Comment: @Notlikethat Thank you; I saw that #16 (and even was thinking "isn't q 128 bits?") but never put it all together. My NEON definitely is very rusty :D Please feel free to edit his answer anywhere else I've misled (or write your own to replace it). This is not my specialty.